# Converting a decimal to IEEE754 32-bit binary number

Tags: number-formats, binary

> Convert 0.625 to IEEE754 32-bit binary number.

```
0.625 x 2 = 1.250
0.250 x 2 = 0.500
0.500 x 2 = 1.000
```

So,

```
0.625 = 0.101  
=> 0.625 = 1.01 x 2^(-1)
```

So,

```
S = 0
E = -1+127 = 126 => 01111110
M = 01 => 0100000 00000000 00000000
```

I am confused with the mantissa part.

Would it be

```
M = 01 => 0100000 00000000 00000000
```

Or,

```
M = 01 => 0000000 00000000 00000001
```

?

Comment: 0.625 = 1.01 * 2^(-1). 5 = 1.01 * 2^2. And the exponent is biased.

Comment: You wrote 0.625 = 1.01 * 2^2, when really 5 = 1.01 * 2^2. And your correction is still wrong: 0.625 = 1.01 * 2^(-1), not 1.01 * 2^(-2).

Comment: @gnasher729, is it correct now?